# Which time-complexity is better O(logM + logN) or O(logM.logN)?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, binary-search, array-algorithms

I tried the binary search on the 2D matrix and I got the solution which gives the time compexity to be the O(logN.logM). There exist already a solution which performs it in log(MN)
time. I Only want to know which is better or less-time taking. Really a burning question.

Comment: Well, if M = N, which is better, O(log N) or O(log^2 N)?

Comment: What is better, P+Q or PQ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah, I must have been asleep. I removed the commend.

Answer (score 2):

Well the question is some what ambigous. If you want to ask if `O(logM+logN) > O(logM*logN)` then the answer is no, `O(logM+logN)` is always less than `O(logM*logN)`.
In the body of the question you say that your complexity is `O(logN*logM)` and the complexity of a known algorithm is `O(log(MN))`. Since `O(log(MN)) = O(log(M)+log(N))` we can say that `O(log(M)*log(N)) > O(log(MN))`

Comment: I believe you made a typo. It sounds like you're saying that `O(logN*logM)` is the same as `O(log(MN))`

Comment: Yes you are right. The correct one is than since 'O(log(MN)) = O(log(M)+log(N))' we can say that for 'M,N' going to infinity 'O(log(M)*log(N)) > O(log(MN))'. I'm going to edit the answer. Hope it is correct this time

Comment: Appreciate your answer thanks.